# Getting session variables from c# to a different aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get strings that I have put in my session variables to another aspx webform. I am getting it inside my JS script and I would like to know how to go about it. I have tried the following but it doesnt seem to work. Please anyone guide me a bit.

Home.aspx.cs

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["InstitutionID"] = BankID;
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["InstitutionName"] = txtBankName.Text.Trim();
```

Index.aspx

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
              var param1var ='<%= Session["InstitutionID"]%>';
              var param2var = '<%= Session["InstitutionName"]%>';
                  console.log('param1', param1var);
                  console.log('param1', param2var);
    ........
    })
```

Comment: What isn't working? Does setting the variable work? Reading it? Any error?

Comment: Try using `<% Response.Write(Session["InstitutionID"]); %>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState.Session object to get the session object data in the Javascript? That is how I use it in one of my WebForms projects. Hope it helps.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.SessionStateVariables.LoginFailed] = false;

var loginIsFailed = '<%=Session[XYZProcet.Common.Constants.SessionStateVariables.LoginFailed]%>';
```